# How to scan printers on Nessus?

Tags: printer, security, nessus

When I try to scan a printer with Nessus 4.4.1 I got the following message:

> Do not scan printers The remote host appears to be a fragile device
>   and will not be scanned.

How can I enable printers scanning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polcies -> Preferences -> Do not scan fragile devices -> Scan Network Printers

Bear in mind that this may result in pages of random characters/service fingerprints being printed, and the printer may end up crashing. This is the default setting for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Polices" menu

Select your target policy

Then "Edit" button

In "Preferences" choose "Do not scan fragile devices" plugin

Check "Scan Network Printers"